# pretty is not defined in fastify pretty print

Tags: node.js, fastify

I'm trying to use `prettyprint: true` on fastify logger options like this:

```
const build = require("./app");

const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    const app = await build({
      logger: {
        prettyPrint: true
      },
    });

    const PORT = process.env.PORT;
    await app.listen(PORT);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

startServer().catch();
```

This code is from **official docs** from [here](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Testing/) and [here](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Logging/).

The `pino-pretty` package is installed

And I get this error when I try to run server:

```
const formatted = pretty(typeof redact === 'function' ? redact(obj) : obj)
                        ^

TypeError: pretty is not a function
```

Checked for this line of code (/node_modules/pino/lib/tools.js 282), `pretty` type is `object`, but in the code it is used as `function`

```
const formatted = pretty(typeof redact === 'function' ? redact(obj) : obj)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution

1. Install `pino` and `pino-pretty` packages (`npm i pino pino-pretty`)
2. Initialize logger by requiring `pino` and adding `pretty-print: true` to options

```
const build = require("./app");

const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    const app = await build({
      logger: require("pino")({ prettyPrint: true }), // here
    });

    await app.listen(app.config.PORT);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

startServer().catch();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the googlers, since i was not sure how to ue fastify logger with typescript, you can obtain pretty the same result using:

```
const envToLogger = {
development: {
transport: {
  target: 'pino-pretty',
  options: {
    translateTime: 'HH:MM:ss Z',
    ignore: 'pid,hostname',
  },
},
},
production: true,
test: false,
}
```

And then:

```
const server = Fastify({
   logger:  envToLogger["development"], // or your env in general
 })
```

More here: https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Logging#enable-logging